# Optimization of Data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have some guessed input data (X0) which I want to optimize them in multiple functions as described below.

X0 = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K] #each element is a float value

Functions:

F1 = A + B + C + D - 200 = 0

F2 = C + D + E - 50 = 0

F3 = C + D + E + F + G - 45 = 0

F4 = E + F + G + H + I + J + K - 67 = 0

F5 = H + I + J + K - 64 = 0

I'm not sure how scipy can optimize the input data in multiple functions.
I prepared a script below; I'm not sure if it's responsive.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize    

x0 = np.array([1. for i in range(11)])    
def my_function(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K):
    F1 = A + B + C + D - 200
    F2 = C + D + E - 50
    F3 = C + D + E + F + G - 45
    F4 = E + F + G + H + I + J + K - 67
    F5 = H + I + J + K - 64
    return F1 + F2 +F3 +F4 + F5

cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'my_function': lambda A, B, C, D:  A + B + C + D - 200},
    {'type': 'ineq', 'my_function': lambda C, D, E: C + D + E - 50},
    {'type': 'ineq', 'my_function': lambda C, D, E, F, G: C + D + E + F + G - 45},
    {'type': 'ineq', 'my_function': lambda E, F, G, H, I, J, K: E + F + G + H + I + J + K - 67},
    {'type': 'ineq', 'my_function': lambda H, I, J, K: H + I + J + K - 64})

res = minimize(my_function, x0, method='BFGS', constraints=cons )
```

Comment: create a function `def my_function` where the arguments of the functions will be `A`, `B`, `C`, .... `K`. Then, sum all values of `F`, i.e. this function will return `F1`+`F2`+....+`F5`. This is your objetive function now. Use then `scipy.optmize.minimize` on this function passing as initial values an array of `N` elements with arbitrary values, and you're done. The only detail is to pass constraints. The constraints are 5 lambda functions, which are your five `F`s

Comment: I prepared a script above; but I'm not sure if it's correct.

Comment: you are very close. Just posted a fix to your code, take a look :}

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works.  One question : Can I import the functions only in constrains? Because when I exclude the functions from my_function(X) and only "A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K = X" is remained and return it to any scalar, it works and  I get the same results.

Comment: Sure, I just went with the intuition of minimizing the relationship of your functions. That could be more necessary if their relationship were non-linear. But all your functions are linear functions, so you can just return the sum of their values and minimize that. I Just made sure to state the general idea for you to be able to generalize to nonlinearity situations ;}

Comment: When I increase the number of constraints I face with such error:  "Error in `/usr/bin/python': corrupted size vs. prev_size: 0x0000000002aecbb0"

Comment: I think this error is much more meaningful: python: malloc.c:3722: _int_malloc: Assertion `(unsigned long) (size) >= (unsigned long) (nb)' failed

Comment: maybe you shoulda skis this in a separate, new question so that more people can take a look at it

Comment: I generated the constraints by loop but the results are not the same in the script that I shared below.

Comment: I think I must use lambda x, i=i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. Use type `eq` (equality) instead of inequality. In addition, your constraints should only receive one argument, which is the array of values, and you just access their positions.

Check the following:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize    

x0 = np.random.random(size=[11])
def my_function(X):
    A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K = X
    F1 = A + B + C + D - 200
    F2 = C + D + E - 50
    F3 = C + D + E + F + G - 45
    F4 = E + F + G + H + I + J + K - 67
    F5 = H + I + J + K - 64
    return F1 + F2 +F3 +F4 + F5

cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda X: X[0] + X[1] + X[2] + X[3] - 200},
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda X: X[2] + X[3] + X[4] - 50},
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda X: X[2] + X[3] + X[4] + X[5] + X[6] - 45},
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda X: X[4] + X[5] + X[6] + X[7] + X[8] + X[9] + X[10] - 67},
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda X: X[7] + X[8] + X[9] + X[10] - 64})

res = minimize(my_function, x0, constraints=cons)
```

Returns

```
success: True
x: array([79.27328348, 78.72671652, 21.16500123, 20.83499877,  8.        ,
       -2.5794818 , -2.4205182 , 15.7738023 , 16.59847106, 15.92703282,
       15.70069382])
```

Answer (score 0):

In the script below I wanted to generate the constraints throughout a loop form (cons2) but the results output from the loop are different from the one that I used a non-loop (cons2) form. I expected to get a same result from both.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

import numpy as np

np.random.seed(15)

x0 = np.random.random(size=[11])


def my_function(X):
    A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K = X
    F1 = A + B + C + D - 200
    F2 = C + D + E - 50
    F3 = C + D + E + F + G - 45
    F4 = E + F + G + H + I + J + K - 67
    F5 = H + I + J + K - 64
    return F1 + F2 +F3 +F4 + F5

#the constraints without loop
cons1 = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda X: X[0] + X[1] + X[2] + X[3] - 200},
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda X: X[2] + X[3] + X[4] - 50},
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda X: X[2] + X[3] + X[4] + X[5] + X[6] - 45},
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda X: X[4] + X[5] + X[6] + X[7] + X[8] + X[9] + X[10] - 67},
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda X: X[7] + X[8] + X[9] + X[10] - 64})

data = [200, 50, 45, 67, 64]
ran = [[0,3], [2,4], [2,6], [4,10], [7,10]]
_tmp= []

#the constraints with loop
for hh in range(5):    
     _tmp.append({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda X: sum([X[i] for i in range(ran[hh][0], ran[hh][1]+1)]) - data[hh]})

cons2 = tuple(_tmp)

#the outputs below must be the same, but it's not.

res1 = minimize(my_function, x0, constraints=cons1)
res2 = minimize(my_function, x0, constraints=cons2)
print res1.x
print res2.x
```