# Generating constraints for optimization in scipy using loop

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

There are lots of constraints which I will use in optimization using scipy; so I need to generate the constraints by loop. Below there's a sample of my constraints:

```
cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -x[0] - 2 * x[1] + 2},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -x[1] - 2 * x[1] + 2},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -x[2] - 2 * x[1] + 2})
```

There constraints are more than three...
I use following loop to generate but I couldn't get the same output.

```
cons ={}
for i in range(50):
    cons['type'] = 'ineq'
    cons['fun'] = lambda x: -x[i] - 2 * x[1] + 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating cons everytime. Try this

```
_tmp = []
for i in range(50):
    _tmp.append({'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -x[i] - 2 * x[1] + 2})

cons = tuple(_tmp)
```

And this is more pythonic

```
cons = tuple([{'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -x[i] - 2 * x[1] + 2} for i in range(50)])
```

Comment: It is a tuple contains dictionary. You should iterate over to print 'type' or simply `print(cons[0]['type'])`

Comment: I used loop in a script that I shared in link below. but I don’t know what the results are different when I use loop. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55855019/optimization-of-data/55858637#55858637

Comment: I think I must use lambda x, i=i

Answer (score 1):

I don't think ozcanyarimdunya's answer would work because the i would be passed as reference instead of value into the constraint dictionary. In other words, in your constraint dictionary, i will always be 49.

The proper way should be:

```
_tmp = []
for i in range(50):
  _tmp.append({'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda x, i = i: -x[i] - 2 * x[1] + 2})

cons = tuple(_tmp)
```